# Opencv libraries in C language. What exactly does this instruction int=pointer==0; ?

Tags: c, opencv

```
CvMat* nextimg = 0;
int firstframe;


firstframe=nextimg==0;
```

if I don't put "==0" returns the following warning:

```
[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a shortened equivalent of

```
int firstframe;
if (nextimg == 0) {
    firstframe = 1;
}
else {
    firstframe = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
firstframe=nextimg==0;
```

It is performing two operations:

1. Check if `nextimg==0`
2. Assign boolean outcome of `#1` to `firstframe`

If you remove the `==0`, statement results in a pointer being assigned to an integer and hence the warning.

Answer (score 0):

`firstframe=nextimg==0;` - Here check is happening for `nextimg` whethet it is equal to zero. Once the check is done return value will be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. That return value will get assigned to `firstframe`. There is no warning because the return value of condition check is assigned here.

`firstframe=nextimg;` - Here value of `nextimg` is assigned to `firstframe`. NULL pointer is assigned to `nextimg` so you are getting that warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's equivalent to this code:

```
CvMat* nextimg = NULL;
int firstframe;

firstframe = (nextimg == NULL);
```

The condition of `nextimg == NULL` returns 0 for false and 1 for true.